# Activity calls another activity and must resume again after another activity finishes

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm new to Android. My problem is:

1. Activity A calls activity B in the middle of its execution
2. Activity B must start and complete its execution
3. Only then activity A must resume (not restart)

Activity A has a loop. Somewhere in the middle of loop, Activity B is called, and once B finishes, A should resume the loop from where it left off.

I tried to code this, but what happens right now is that Activity A calls B, but B is not entered, then A resumes the loop and again calls B.

Essentially, the calls to B are stacked and once the loop in A completes, one by one the calls to B in stack are executed, so finally the first call to B is executed last in a last-in first-out order. I just want to execute B once, at the appropriate time.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: it will when you press back button in B unless A is destroyed

Comment: or if you call 'finish' on B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your activity will resume, when calling the Acticity B, don't finish Activity A. If you need to write some code when it resumes. you can do that by overriding onResume method of Activity A.

Comment: Actually Activity A has a loop. Some where in the middle of loop Activity B is called. After activity B finishes, activity A must resume with the loop. This goes on like again A calls,B finishes, A must resume... How should I implement this? rewriting the loop again in onResume method doesn't seem to be best option..any other suggestion please?

Comment: you can save the loop index when launching B activity by startActivityForResult, finish B with setResult and in OnActivityResult Method in activity A, resume your loop from last saved index. will it work?

Comment: how to save the loop index? remaining part i understood..sorry its just I am a fresher n I donno much..

Comment: no problem. when you are iterating in the loop, save the current location of the loop (i.e. where your loop iterator is) for eg. in "for loop" your index "i". and use that loop index in onActivityResult. if its still not clear, post code for your loop and I'll help you with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!I'll try that n let you know if I encounter any problem in the process....

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong design paradigm for your app. You should not start another activity like that. Keep the code on separate modules by all means, but do not start another activity just to transfer control.

Comment: Starting another activity is not always bad. If it is necessary - go ahead, but it should be avoided when possible

Comment: In my case, its really too hard widout a loop..But I'll make sure of remembering that @Philip Sheard

Comment: I an not suggesting that you get rid of the loop. I am suggesting that you get rid of the activity start. It is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Starting [Activity for result](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html). You can start Activity B for some result, and when Activity B finishes, the `onActivityResult` method of Activity A will be called and you can set it to continue/start work there.

**EDIT**
Based on your updated question you can try:

1. Create a method in Activity A which starts a loop
2. When you decide you want to call Activity B
   2.1 Exit the loop, and save to where the loop is
   2.2 Start Activity B for result
3. When Activity B finishes and returns you some kind of result, you will restart the loop (form the point you saved in step 2.1) in Activity A

Comment: Well that pretty much depends on what you are doing in the loop. If you are traversing a list - just save the index. If you are doing some calculations - save your current result of the calculations and start from there next time.  
Again I say - it pretty much depends on what you are doing in your loop